# Change/replace part of an URL contained WITHIN a function

Tags: javascript, replace, google-sheets

Not sure if this is even possible. But ideally, I'd like visitors to my site to be able to type a unique identification number in an input field,  click submit, and have another script replace the Google sheet reference ("`DATA1`") with their own ID number.

So, effectively change the queried url. Here's part the script/url users need to modify:

```
function loadChart() {
  var query = new google
    .visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=...&sheet=DATA1');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}
```

Would it be possible to use/modify something like the following code to do the trick

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("get").innerHTML; 
  var changeit = str.replace("DATA2", document.getElementById('textbox').value);
  document.getElementById("get").innerHTML = changeit;
}
```

Thanks for any help or direction you can provide

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of including DATA1 in the URL, append it with data coming from f.ex a textbox:

```
function loadChart() {
  var txtbox = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=...&sheet=' + txtbox;
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(url);

  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU ROBERT MCKEE! I've been trying to figure this out for the past two days. So simple I want to slap myself!